# Does document reference increase read count?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `users` collection and a `rentals` collection. A `rental` document has a field for the user who is renting the item, stored as a document reference (`rentalDocumentSnapshot['renter'] = /users/<some id here>`). To query all the rentals where you are the renter, I just pass into a stream:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('rentals')
    .where('renter', isEqualTo: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(myUserID))
    .snapshots()
```

Does calling `Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(myUserID)` create a read? So would it be better to store the user ID in the rental as a string instead of a document reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a DoucumentReference doesn't incur a read.  You have to actually `get()` that document in order to read it.  You can think of a reference as just a pointer to a document.

Storing a reference instead of an ID or path is not necessarily better or worse.  It's mostly a matter of convenience and preference.  References are generally easier to use, since you don't have to build that reference, but as I said, building that reference is free.  A reference will generally store more data, as it's storing the entire path to the document, not just the ID.